# Some questions on Elmah

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, elmah

I am currently working with Elmah and really like it. I've a couple questions on it though:

Is there any way when I log an exception that I can add custom data to the exception logging that will get logged with the exception?

When an error occurs on my site, I would like to be able to redirect the user to an error page and for it to include a unique identifier for the exception that gets logged with the exception but also shown on screen so I can track it back when a user reports it. Is this possible?

Is there instructions anywhere to would tell me I can set up logging of exceptions to disk?

Answer (score 2):

You can add to the data collection of any exception. You can do this in a try catch block,  Application_Error handler in Global.asax, or a registered HandleErrorAttribute.

```
exception.Data.Add("key", "additional info");
```

You may log to file using Elmah's configuration. Ensure you have set user permissions to this location.

```
<elmah>
<security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
<errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/ErrorLogs" />
</elmah>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Request/Response patern. If user get exception set response false, log the error with Elmah and return error message with unique error Id to the end user. You can see code example below:

```
public class Response
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorLog
{
    public static string GenerateErrorRefMessageAndLog(Exception exception)
    {
        string uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Exception newEx = new Exception(uniqueId, exception);
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(newEx);
        return String.Format("If you wish to contact us please quote reference '{0}'", uniqueId); 
    }
}

public class YourClass
{
    var response = new Response();

    try
    {
      //Bussines logic here
      response.Success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Shield Exceptions
        response.Message = ErrorLog.GenerateErrorRefMessageAndLog(ex);
        response.Success = false;
    }            
    return response;
}
```

This is url how to configurate Elmah.
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs